# How to make a Django ImageField save the image to another model?

Tags: django, image, inline, models, imagefield

I have a member profiles application that stores simple information about members of a team.  Part of the profile is an image to be used as an avatar.  I've been using [Photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) to create standard galleries of photos, but it has an [ImageModel](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/ImageModel) that can be extended to take advantage of Photologue's resizing and caching functionality.

The problem is, the example they give on their page looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from photologue.models import ImageModel

class UserPortrait(ImageModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
```

I could replace User with Member and all would be good, except for the fact that editing the profile becomes a two step process; First I'd have to create a Member profile, then create a UserPortrait and associate it with the Member.  I'd like to streamline this back into a single step process, as if I were using an ImageField.

I've overridden image fields at the form level and the admin.py level, but I'm wondering if I can deal with this at the model level or even the field level.  I'd like to have the inline functionality of an ImageField but still have the file managed by a separated, related model.  Actual model inlines seem like overkill since its just one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Member class should extend ImageModel. There is no need for an additional class (e.g. UserPortrait).

Comment: I suppose the example is how you'd have to do it for Users since the User class can't be extended.

Comment: I decided to go the inline route since I reasoned that I may want more than one image associated with a profile at some point.